# Graph of summation of absolute functions

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, absolute-value

> Let $f$ be defined on $[-2,2]$ as
>   $$f(x)=\begin{cases}-1&-2\le x\le0\\x-1&0\le x\le2\end{cases}$$
>   If
>   $g(x)=f(|x|)+|f(x)|$, then find g(x).

I have drawn $f(x)$:
[image]
How do I draw $g(x)$ from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a picture will be the clearest possible answer, but if you need more explanations just ask!

[image]

Comment: This is so helpful. Clearly illustrated with graphs. Could you please tell me which charting tool have you used?

Comment: To be honest... I've drawn it by hand with a graphical tool, not a mathematical one. I didn't want to struggle with the piecewise definition of your funcion... @Saurav

Comment: Can I have the name of the graphical tool, please?

Comment: Name and link, here you are: [Compass and Ruler](http://car.rene-grothmann.de/doc_en/)

Answer (score 0):

for $f(|x|)$, it's simply to remove the portion of negative $x- axis$   and mirror the remaining graph along y axis. Thus $f(|x|)=|x|-1$ (you can see it via your function too. $-1$ becomes irrelevant as $|x|\notin[-2,0]$.

for $|f(x)|$ simply remove the negative y- axis portion of graph and mirror the remaining about x- axis. this graph have , surprisingly no contribution towards net result as at each $x$ there present a corresponding $y$, $-y$ pair which will cance out each other.

Therefore the required graph is nothing but $y=|x|-1$